# MySQL insert category rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

I'm struggling describing the problem in the Title, let alone looking for a solution that may well exist, so please excuse, or point me to the thread. I need to *pad* rows, so I have 4 rows per Category as in the simplified scenario below:

```
mysql> select * from a;
+-------+
|  Num  |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     3 |
|     4 |
+-------+
mysql> select * from b;
+----------+------+------+
| Category | Num  | Data |
+----------+------+------+
| X        |    2 |   10 |
| X        |    3 |   12 |
| X        |    4 |    8 |
| Y        |    1 |    0 |
| Y        |    2 |   19 |
| y        |    3 |   15 |
| y        |    4 |   22 |
| Z        |    2 |   10 |
+----------+------+------+
```

The result I need is always 4 rows per category (table b will always ever have one of Num = 1, 2, 3 or 4 per category), set data = null for the padded rows:

```
mysql> select * from c;
+----------+------+------+
| Category | Num  | Data |
+----------+------+------+
| X        |    1 | NULL |
| X        |    2 |   10 |
| X        |    3 |   12 |
| X        |    4 |    8 |
| Y        |    1 |    0 |
| Y        |    2 |   19 |
| y        |    3 |   15 |
| y        |    4 |   22 |
| Z        |    1 | NULL |
| Z        |    2 |   10 |
| Z        |    3 | NULL |
| Z        |    4 | NULL |
+----------+------+------+
```

I created table **a** artificially, as I thought it may help with the (INSERT) query?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `cross join` table `a` with all available categories in table `b`, and then bring table `b` with a `left join`.

```
select 
    c.category,
    a.num,
    b.data
from a
cross join (select distinct category from b) c
left join b on b.category = c.category and b.num = a.num
```

You can easily turn this to an `insert` query to another table:

```
insert into c(category, num, data)
select 
    c.category,
    a.num,
    b.data
from a
cross join (select distinct category from b) c
left join b on b.category = c.category and b.num = a.num
```

Comment: @Akina: OP did not mention that so I am not too worried about it for now. I think they are mainly looking for the `cross join`/`left join` logic here.

Comment: @GMB thx for such a quick answer, which I'm just now trying to digest.  It works for my simplified scenario, will apply it to the actual thing soon.

Even though the use of "b" for the temp query in the suggested answer threw me for a moment, as this was the name of the desired output table, the answer taught me what I still have to learn, even after working with SQL for some years now ;-)

Comment: @Akina: thanks for the caution, even though I need to reflect on what your warning is about.  Are you saying GMB's solution is dependent on the physical row ordering of table **a** and/or **b**?

If it's about the physical order of output rows, this is not relevant to my problem.

Comment: @MatthiasOtto *Are you saying GMB's solution is dependent on the physical row ordering of table a and/or b?* o_O I mean that `'Y'` and `'y'` may be NOT equal...

Comment: @Akina & GMB: Case-sensitivity is not an issue for me.  I thought _collation_ is about ordering data, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @MatthiasOtto Ordering and comparing... in this case - during DISTINCT.

Comment: @Akina the category is derived from b in the DISTINCT, how would in conflict with any other Category?

Comment: @Akina, you're right, I forgot to say that Category is unique in **b** (irrespective of upper/lower spelling).

Comment: @MatthiasOtto [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e3ced09024bb669abf92d52a72bef506)

Answer (score 0):

You need left join

```
select a.num, b.category , b.data
from tablea a
left join tableb b on a.num = b.num
```

and for insert

```
insert into tablec (num, category, data)
select a.num, b.category , b.data
from tablea a
left join tableb b on a.num = b.num
```

of if need  an update   for the exing rows

```
update tablec c
inner join ( 
select a.num, b.category , ifnull(b.data,0)
from tablea a
left join tableb b on a.num = b.num ) t t.num= c.num  and t.category = c.category
set data  = t.data
```

Comment: thx, I replaced "tablea/b" with "a/b" in the SELECT to make it error-free but didn't get the desired result :-(

It basically selects table **b** (in MySQL).

Comment: check better  ..  there is  join on num  and the qeuery must return value form both the table  ..  whit null value for not matching rows